# The fastest way to import txt/xlsx files to Access by Macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I want to Import all files(txt or xlsx from folder)
I Already Created macro to do it.
( All columns have to be as char)

To Import txt files i generate schema.ini file.
To import excel files i used sql but it was so slow, so i choosed another way.

Both of macro creating table, then put records into them.

Score:
Txt files:
18 files , every database have 4 colummns full of records.
18 txt files had 249584 , it's like 969 688 cells.
Time: 20 seconds.

Excel file:
1 files , 8 colummns , 14000 records  , it's like 110880 Cells(cells aren't empty)
Time: 75 seconds.

P.S Everyfile have got another structure(number of colummns etc.). Everycolumn in Database have to be as Varchar(255)

Btw:
Do you know any good solution to export all database in Access to txt?
Is it possible to check code page of txt files?( by using VBA or Emeditor.)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I trying to import Excel file to Access ( with creating columns , setting code page etc) - But my idea take too much time. - 75 seconds. Want to get same speed as like txt file.I'm trying to get information about code page in txt files.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx

DoCmd.TransferText is pretty baller. You might need to set up a import spec though.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "spec name", "table name", "filename"
```

With excel files you have DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet which has its own argumments, but you cant use a spec with it. You could also write code to read excel files into a text delimited file and import form there (i do this on the reg).

Here is an untested way to create a pipedelimited text file to use. It is untested and Im not willing to do anything else for free for you. If you cant figure it out form here, then too bad. Things you can google to help fill in the blanks: Late Binding, Write to text file, Dir Function, Excel range to array.

Happy Coding :)

```
dim NewTextFile as String
dim oXL as Object
dim sep as string
dim path as string
dim fileName as string
Dim bringOver as variant
dim sheet as object
dim wholeline as string

sep "|"
path = "path to excel file"
fileName = "name of excelfile.xlsx"

NewTextFile = "path you want file saved to" & "\name.txt"
Set oXL = WorkBooks.Open(path & fileName)
With oXL
    Open NewTextFile For Output As #2
    For Each sheet in oXL.Sheets
        bringOver = sheet.UsedRange
        for i = LBound(bringOver,1) to UBound(bringOver,1)
            for j = LBound(bringOver,2) to UBound(bringOVer,2)
                wholeline = wholeline & bringOver(i,j) & sep
            next j
            Write #2, wholeline
            wholelline = vbNullString
        Next i
    Next sheet
End With
```

Comment: I can't use DoCmd command - because i can't set code page,sep etc..            But idea about save excel as csv then import isn't good. Because to do it fast i have to use method: Save as , then it gonna save to csv with (;)delim  But if some records have got ";" in string it will be wrong.

Comment: pipe delimited is something you could do too

Comment: But by using default: "save as" i can't put delimiter which one i want.(yea i can but i have to change settings in windows)

Comment: if you create your own text file form reading the csv you can

Comment: You mean schema.ini working too while using "save as"? Can you give more info?

Comment: @R.Pitagram I edited my answer to give you a skeleton for creating a pipe delimited text file. Since this isnt a code writing site, youre on your own from here. However I did basically pave the way to help you figure it out on  your own

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all files, and import each, like this.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

 Dim strPathFile As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 ' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the CSV files
 strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

 ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
 ' the data are to be imported

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")


 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile

       ' Link CSV Files
       DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

       ' Import Excel Files
       ' DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet , , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames


 ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
 ' file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()

 Loop

End Sub
```